# How to detect fixed focus camera blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can i detect models with fixed focus camera using java development in blackberry OS 6.0 > ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `FocusControl.isAutoFocusSupported()` to check if the camera can do auto focus. If not then its fixed focus.

Comment: Is there any way without creating a player?

Comment: No you cant. Other way is to have a list of fixed focus devices in the server. When the app starts, download the list and check to see if this device is in the list. Everytime a new device is launched, you can update the list.